# Need to open File Explorer with the Samba server shared folder

Tags: c#, linux, samba

I am connecting successfully with the Samba server with the following code. I need to open File Explorer with the Samba server shared folder.

```
SMB2Client client = new SMB2Client();
bool isConnected = client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.169"), SMBTransportType.DirectTCPTransport);

 if (isConnected)
 {
      NTStatus status = client.Login(String.Empty, "mint", "test12345");
      if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
      {          {
          List shares = client.ListShares(out status);
          Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"\\192.168.1.169\sambashare");
          client.Logoff();
      }

      client.Disconnect();
      Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

This is not opening anything. **Also, I can't access the subdirectory of that folder.**

Comment: I guess, it's working on a different account. Can you please check Taskmanager for running explorer instances?

Comment: There's no Windows Explorer in Linux. And there's no need for an SMB client just to open a shared folder. Just open it like any local folder. `Process.Start("explorer.exe",@"\\server\sharename\directory")`. SMB is the networking protocol used by Windows, you don't need any extra clients. Or credentials. File shares work using the credentials of the currently logged in Windows account.

Comment: This is opening with my computer > Documents folder @MarkusMeyer

Comment: That's because you're using the wrong path. File shares start with "\\". The format is `\\servername\shared_folder`. That `SmbClient` class is doing absolutely nothing at all - `Process.Start` will start another process. That different process will use the path argument to open the folder without being affected by classes in your application. That process, Windows Explorer, will run under *you* Windows account, or at least the account that launched your application

Comment: Can you navigate to that share yourself? Copy the path and use it as-is in your program. What you do is no different than hitting Win+R and pasting a folder path

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It asking for a password and while I am passing the password of the samba server then getting also access denied.

Comment: That's because you aren't connecting to an actual Windows shared folder even a correctly configured Linux file server. Shared folders are NOT meant to be used with explicit usernames and passwords. ONLY when working in workgroup (instead of an Active Directory domain), do you have to provide the credentials of a Windows account local to that file server. Again, your `SmbClient` class doesn't affect how your Windows machine works and certainly not how Windows Explorer works.

Comment: If you can't access a shared folder from Windows Explorer, you won't be able to access it from code either. You'll have to either fix the misconfigured SMB server (why isn't it part of a domain?) and ensure your account is allowed to access the folder, or find the correct credentials and access files through that `SmbClient` class. Once again though, that's not how shared folders are supposed to work. Using a single account for everyone is *extremely insecure*. Might as well open the server to everyone, since everyone will use the same password